# Change percentage of increase and decrease of screen brightness

Tags: kde, manjaro, backlight

Currently I work in manjaro on a laptop with KDE, the problem that appears to me is the following:
Increasing or decreasing the screen brightness goes from 7 to 7.
But I need the increment to be 5 by 5.

I have tried the following:

```
xbacklight +5
```

Try modifying the **scale** file that is in:

```
/ sys / class / backlight / intel_backlight
```

But it does not allow me to update it even granting r / w permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try

`xbacklight -inc 5`

and

`xbacklight -dec 5`

You can even set keyboard shortcuts to use the commands with hotkeys, if you want, in System Settings > Shortcuts, I think (I just started with KDE but I've done it for years in Xfce).

Also, the /sys directory doesn't have normal files you can change. It's an ever-changing virtual filesystem similar to /proc.

[Directory - /sys in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/794198/directory-sys-in-linux)